# Joomla Events Override

Tags: php, joomla

Is it possible for plugins to block System Events in Joomla? I'm currently using a url rewriting plugin and the onAfterRoute event does not seem to be called (which I need for another plugin)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins shouldn't be blocking the `onAfterRoute` event. However, plugins responding to that event must be published after they are installed.

Also, `onAfterRoute` is called after the URL is parsed and variables have been pushed into `JRequest`. Is this this point where you're wanting the plugin to be called, or does it need to come before `onAfterRoute`?

Answer (score 0):

Does the other plugin (the one that uses `onAfterRoute`) work if you disable the URL rewriting plugin? If not, then that's not the problem.

If it does, then I suggest you look at the plugin and find the bit that targets `onAfterRoute` to see what it's doing. (Maybe post it here if it's not too involved.)